# Excel 2010 Macro to compare more then two columns for finding the matched value via macro or VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets (sheet1 and sheet 2) in sheet1 there is more than two columns I want to match or check the difference value; column name are `Chq. No.`, `Name` and `Amount` in sheet1 and sheet2.

**Sheet 1**

```
Date       Chq. No. Name             Amount 
9/22/2015   22      REETA            1,400.00 
9/21/2015   30      SUMIRTA          1,400.00 
8/18/2015   31      NIRDUL KUMARI    200.00 
8/21/2015   56      JAGDAMBA MISHRA  200.00 
8/21/2015   58      ARUN KUMARI      200.00 
8/21/2015   59      SANTOSH KUMARI   200.00
```

**Sheet2**

```
9/22/2015   22      REETA            1,400.00 
9/21/2015   30      SUMIRTA          1,400.00 
8/18/2015   33      NIRDUL KUMARI    200.00 
8/21/2015   55      JAGDAMBA MISHRA  200.00 
8/21/2015   58      ARUN KUMARI      200.00 
8/21/2015   60      SANTOSH KUMARI   200.00
```

My side I am sharing the example with I am facing in actual, kindly help me.

Comment: what you want to do after matching?

Answer (score 0):

Nitin in your case Cheque no is best field to match both databases,, you can use this one

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1! $B2,Sheet2! $B$2:$B$10,0)),"No match in B","")

Or you can use either this,

=INDEX(Sheet1! $A$2:$C$6,MATCH(Sheet2! $A 2,Sheet1! $A$2:$C$6,0))